# Solr and Rails: [* TO *] value instead of nil (asterisk TO asterisk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, solr-query-syntax

Inside my model at `searchable` block I have index `time added_at`.

At `search` block for searching I added `with(:added_at, nil)`, made reindex and now inside `search` object I have:

```
<Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["-added_at_d:[* TO *]"]...}>
```

What is the meaning of this [* TO *] ? Something went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `with(:added_at, nil)` you narrow down the search results to documents having no values in the field *added_at*, so we can expect the corresponding query filter to be defined as :

```
fq=>["added_at_d:null"] # not valid
```

The problem is that Solr Standard Query Parser does not support searching a field for empty/null value. In this situation the filter needs to be negated (exluding documents having any value in the field) so that the query remains valid.

The operator `-` can be used to exclude the field, and the wildcard character `*` can be used to match any value, now we can expect the query filter to look like :

```
fq=>["-added_at_d:*"]
```

However, although the above is valid for the query parser, using a range query should be preferred to prevent inconsitent behaviors when using wildcard within negative subqueries.

> Range Queries allow one to match documents whose field(s) values are
>   between the lower and upper bound specified by the Range Query. Range
>   Queries can be inclusive or exclusive of the upper and lower bounds.
>
> A `*` may be used for either or both endpoints to specify an open-ended range query.

Eventually there is nothing wrong with this filter that ends up looking like :

```
fq=>["-added_at_d:[* TO *]"]
```

cf. [Lucene Range Queries](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Range_Searches), [Solr Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-DifferencesbetweenLuceneQueryParserandtheSolrStandardQueryParser)